# load more items in Listview from ViewModel in xamarin forms

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.forms

How to load more items in Listview from ViewModel ?

Code Implemented :

```
listview.ItemAppearing += (sender, e) => 
        {
            if(isLoading || Items.Count == 0)
                return;

            //hit bottom!
            if(e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
            {
                LoadItems();
            }
        };
```

in my xaml.cs

But need to do the same in my ViewModel...

Comment: The newer CollectionView has built-in 'load more' support, and is generally recommended over the (old) ListView.

Comment: Can you get ViewModel instance in where you called listview.ItemAppearing? If so, you can call vm.loadMore() inside listview.ItemAppearing.

Answer (score 0):

try the following thing & let me know if you need some more help.

> I used `MessagingCenter` to achieve it.

1. In your xaml.cs file add this

```
public partial class Results : ContentPage
    {
        public Results()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
            listview.ItemAppearing += (object s, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e) => 
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Search:LastResultShown", e);
            };
        }
    }
```

2. Now subscribe to your `MessagingCenter` in your ViewModel & remember to unsubscribe it as well.

```
public class ResultsVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public ResultsVM() : base()
    {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Results, ItemVisibilityEventArgs>(this, "Search:LastResultShown", OnItemAppearing);
    }

    public override void CleanupPage()
    {
        base.CleanupPage();
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Results, ItemVisibilityEventArgs>(this, "Search:LastResultShown");
    }

    private async void OnItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
         //Here will be your code
           if ( ResultsList.Count == 0 || e == null || e.Item == null ) { return; }
            var lastItem = ResultsList.ElementAtOrDefault(ResultsList.Count - 1);
            if ( lastItem != null && e.Item == lastItem ) { LoadNextItems(); }
         
    }
}
```

> `OnItemAppearing` will hit everytime when your list comes at the end of screen.